# How can I fill an empty div partitioned using bootstrap grid system with a specific color?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Consider this case

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3"></div>
</div>
```

In this case, suppose if I need to fill the first div (first column) within the parent div with a background of #FF0000 how can I do it? If I can do it in a regular way, that is by specifying the style="background-color:red", the background changes only for the content written within it. Not if I create another div inside it and set its height and width to 100% nothing happens. Why is it so? And how can I do it the correct way?

Answer (score 8):

Use a `&nbsp;`

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">&nbsp;</div>
```

And set the background color as you wish.

Simple and elegant.

Answer (score 4):

Empty `div` has no height. Use `height`, `min-height`, `padding-top` or `padding-bottom` to make empty `div` visible. You may do it

1. by class for column
2. by class for row with `:first-child`

Bootstrap uses `col-xs-` for screens of any width [if there are no other conditions](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries). Therefore `col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3` is equivalent to `col-xs-3`.

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.make-first-div-red > div:first-child,
.make-it-red {
  background-color: #f00;
  min-height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
)
```

```html
<div class="row make-first-div-red">
  <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-3 make-it-red"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="bg col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">adadadadada</div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3"></div>
</div>
```

and use this css
    `.bg{background:#FF0000}`
and it will work

Comment: Actually, I want the background to be empty and be filled with the redcolor. But in this method, only the line containing some content gets its padding the color of #FF0000. What should I do?

Comment: use height, give it a height:20px or whatever and it will be red without content